# How to compare SQL rows based on values and obtain a sum?

Tags: php, mysql

I am attempting to upgrade an Old Custom eCommerce system. I am trying to make a log of quantity changes made to an item based on rows from a table (call it "old_table") that the old custom system creates. I can't seem to be able to crack this problem.

As someone starts to make a change to an Item in the system, it creates a record in the "old_table" with the values:

```
 Time                | User   | Current Qty | Status | Item
 -----------------------------------------------------------
 2015-07-09 05:30:47 | Admin  | 10          | Start  | ABC 1
```

When the person finishes changing the quantity for an Item in the system, it creates a record in the "old_table" with the values:

```
 Time                | User   | Current Qty | Status | Item
 -----------------------------------------------------------
 2015-07-09 05:50:47 | Admin  | 09          | End    | ABC 1
```

*--- Note: Sadly, if the quantity is set to "00" there will not be an "End" entry. I have guessed that i would set a 24 hour limit then would consider that user to have set it to "00" ---*

**My Goal**

In a new Table, I am trying to create a row stating that the User "Admin" subtracted/added a total of "X" of the Item "ABC 1" and if within 24 hours there is no "End" row within the "old_table" for the given item to make a row stating that the User "Admin" set the value to "00".

Anyone have Ideas, suggestions or a solution? I have tried for weeks to solve this. Is it not possible?

Comment: Sorry about that and thanks for pointing that out Shnugo. Its mysql

Answer (score 0):

You tagged this with mysql AND sql-server. Which system/version is the one in use?

With SQL-Server (>=2008) you could use window function (OVER clause: https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms189461.aspx) which gives you grouped count, sum, avg and other aggregate function.

Comment: Any ideas since its MySQL?